# corrupted PDF files from batch copy

Tags: pdf, batch-file, cmd, copy

I'm trying to copy and rename a pdf from my scanner, but the copied file (using the below command) is corrupt.  Is there a trick to making this work?  I have about 10 scans that I need to copy to like 60 names, so I'd rather not do it by hand.  Thanks in advance.

copy c:\users\me\desktop\test.pdf > c:\users\me\desktop\test2.pdf

Comment: I tried the binary switch and the verify switch and no dice.  The specific error message is "Adobe Reader could not open "test2".pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

Comment: Did you take out the redirect symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `>` you don't need it. I tested and just `copy c:\users\me\desktop\test.pdf  c:\users\me\desktop\test2.pdf` works just fine.